# Python logger creates duplicate entries without a message

Tags: python, logging

I have a simple logger set up in my program.

```
 if __name__ == "__main__":

     # Logger setup
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s')
    file_handler= logging.FileHandler('debug.log')
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    <some code to call other methods>

    logger.removeHandler(file_handler)
    del logger, file_handler
```

Now in the other methods (5 in all) I write info to the log file like this.

```
def func1(args):

logger.info("*" * 80 + "\n")
logger.info("Starting test for '{}'\n".format(args))
```

But when I check the debug.log file it has duplicate entries like these:

*

> INFO:**main**:
>   INFO:**main**:
>   INFO:**main**:
>
> INFO:**main**:****************************************************************
>
> INFO:**main**:
>   INFO:**main**:
>   INFO:**main**:
>   INFO:**main**:Starting test for

*

I've tried setting logger.propagate = True/False but that did not help. Could anyone please help me understand what is going on here?

EDIT: All the other functions are in the same file as **main**

Comment: Hi. Are you passing the logger to the function or the functions are getting the logger again? Also, for what I can see, between the two messages with `******` and `Starting test for`, a lot of empty lines are written. The functions are being called concurrently?

Comment: I'm not passing the logger to the functions as an argument. The functions are called one by one.

Comment: The functions must have the logger in their scope, otherwise the only way to use the logger is to get it again with `getLogger` inside the function. The functions that are called inside the `main` are defined in the same module? Maybe you could edit the question and add a little bit of information showing how the functions work exactly.

Comment: Edited the question. Yes all the other functions are in the same file as __main__. Even if I don't pass the logger to the called functions won't they get it from the global scope?